# how to put warnings of makedepend in a file?

Tags: c, makefile, command-prompt, c-preprocessor

I am using makedepend File_Name command. I get warnings and errors from makedepend. I want to put them in a file. I tried makedepend File_Name > output_file. It does not work. How do i do this?

Comment: Warnings generally (when things are well behaved) are sent to standard error and not standard output. `> file` redirects standard output. Use `2> file` to redirect standard error.

Comment: Another common construct is `command > output 2>&1` which sends errors to `output` along with standard output.  More precisely, it redirects standard error to standard output; since the standard output is going to `output` the standard error will as well.